# ubuntu Server Email Not Sent Laravel (SquirrelMail)

Tags: php, laravel, email, server, ubuntu-server

Hello There I have checked all the similar questions but non of the question solved my problem.

My Project is developed on Laravel

My Problem is, When I uploaded my project on Ubuntu serve, I found that Mail is not sent.

When I tested mail on my local computer. It worked perfectly. I tested with mailtrap and gmail. Both worked perfectly.

When I upload on serve, There was an error on sending email. I tested with squirrel mail and gmail. Both method got failed.

When I used gmail the error was
    **Swift_TransportExceptionConnection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]**
and there was no error code on squirrel mail.

My laravel configuration is

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=localhost
MAIL_PORT=25
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: I think your `MAIL_HOST` should not be localhost.

Comment: I used localhost because on my ubuntu server i have installed squirrel mail.

Comment: Oh I see, username passwords are correct ?

Comment: Yes when I tested on Local computer all goes perfectly. I tested with mailtrap and gmail both worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have a blocked port, you might want to disable the firewall to see if changes anything. Otherwise dubblecheck that you're using the correct IP adres.

You can try to disable iptables temporarly:

```
sudo service ufw stop
```

To start it again use:

```
sudo service ufw start
```

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked. Is there any other way??